# uiBinder: style a DisclosurePanel

Tags: css, gwt, styles, uibinder

What's the best way to style (I need to make the headers bolder) that DisclosurePanel?

```
<g:DisclosurePanel>
  <g:header>Menu1</g:header>
  <g:VerticalPanel>
    <g:Hyperlink targetHistoryToken="Entrate">Entrate</g:Hyperlink>
    <g:Hyperlink targetHistoryToken="Uscite">Uscite</g:Hyperlink>
  </g:VerticalPanel>
</g:DisclosurePanel>

<ui:style>
        .gwt-DisclosurePanel .header {
            font-size:20px;
        }   
    </ui:style>
```

Anyway, what's the best practice for styling gwt standard panels, via uibinder?

Comment: Please post the full code sample that includes your `.myclass` modifications.

Comment: something like .myClass .header { font-size:18px; }

Comment: Please edit the question to match the attempt that you made.